# Read and store value from webpage using selenium

Tags: c#, selenium

You may think this question is same as my previous question, but it is not. I have a web page like this:

```
Description      Some Description
Appname          App1
Duration         50
Price            25
```

I am developing a selenium application using c# and I am on middle of it. I want Selenium to retrieve and store both the duration and price values (that is 50 and 25) to the string variables dur and price. But both the values are not hyperlinks and also both of them has got same attributes like classname, id, tagname etc.

I have tried using this code, but it doesn't worked as expected:

```
 string dur;
 string price;
 var elements = driver.FindElements(By.Id("SPFieldNumber"));
 IList<IWebElement> list = elements.ToArray();
 foreach (IWebElement opt in list)
 {
 dur = elements[0].ToString();
 price = elements[1].ToString();
 MessageBox.Show(dur);
 MessageBox.Show(price);
 }
```

The HTML Code that surrounds these fields is as shown below:

```
<td class="ms-formlabel" nowrap="true" width="165px" valign="top">
<h3 class="ms-standardheader">
<a name="SPBookmark_Duration"></a>
Duration
</h3>
</td>
<td id="SPFieldNumber" class="ms-formbody" width="450px" valign="top"> 365  </td>
```

It would be helpful if any one of you could help me on this since my work is on hold now..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: If you could provide the html that surrounds these particular elements, we'll be able to assist further. Thanks.

Comment: @MarkRowlands:Please find my edited question..

Comment: How does it "not work as expected"? What does it do instead?

Comment: @Arran:I was trying to make selenium display the value of those fields.Instead it shows a messagebox with the content as OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxWebElement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now you've explained exactly what it does do, and what you are expecting, I can clearly see the error:

```
IList<IWebElement> list = elements;
foreach (IWebElement opt in list)
{
    dur = elements[0].Text.ToString();
    price = elements[1].Text.ToString();
    MessageBox.Show(dur);
    MessageBox.Show(price);
}
```

You want the `.Text` property, you also don't need the `.ToArray` and you seem as though you want a `for` loop, not a `foreach` loop. That's the different issue though.

Note that I said about the `foreach` loop because you are using a `foreach` loop but still referencing the elements by their index (0, and 1)...that is what a `for` loop is for.

However, you mentioned you only need those first two values, therefore the loops are unnecessary and only causing issues.

Try this code out:

```
IList<IWebElement> list = elements;
string duration = list.First();
string price = list.ElementAt(1);
MessageBox.Show(duration);
MessageBox.Show(price);
```

You may need to add a using for `System.Linq`.

Comment: But how can I use for loop instead of foreach, since more than one content is there with the same ID "SPFieldNumber"??Can you please show me a sample for that?

Comment: Well you are referencing elements 0 and 1 *explicitly* via their index. What do you want to do? In your `elements` list, I would expect to see all the elements with an ID of `SPFieldNumber` ....so what does `dur` and `price` have in them? What are their *exact* values, once you use `.Text` like I suggested?

Comment: The values are like 25 and 50 respectively for duration and price. In short both are of integer type.Hope this is what you meant.

Comment: What other values are in there? I can the first one is Duration, then it's Price, then what? Is the list big? I'm basically trying to see if you actually need to loop through them at all.

Comment: Actually the list is having 11 values, inwhich I need only those two (dur and price). And while executing your code, I could get those two values 9 times, that is those 2 values are shown in message box for 9 times,one by one. But except these 2 values, the ID property is different, for your information.

Comment: Yes and the reason for this is your explicitly looking for the elements at index `0` and `1` in the list, hence my comment. You are mixing `foreach` loop's and `for` loops. Look at my edit. It's very simple to just get those two values. You don't need these loops *at all*.

Comment: Many Thanks for that..My work was on hold for so many days for this 7 lines of code..Many Thanks for that..